# Formal correspondence between Langevin equations and autoregressive processes

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, stochastic-processes

I have seen numerous times that "The continuous version of an autoregressive process is a Langevin equation" or "The discrete version of a Langevin equation is an autoregressive process". For example, see [here](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=VLXVBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT222&lpg=PT222&dq=langevin%20equation%20autoregressive%20process&source=bl&ots=OPcV8G7vTH&sig=ZRlc0loKEFPt-3-13L93bkpGg3s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj47OHvivzKAhUGIKYKHRQXDTUQ6AEIPTAE#v=onepage&q=langevin%20equation%20autoregressive%20process&f=false).

However, I can hardly find any formal treatment of this "correspondence".

To be specific, I would like to know given an autoregressive process:
$$
x_{t}=\sum_{i=1}^p a_px_{t-i}
$$
what is the "corresponding" (generic) Langevin equation?

and

Given a Langevin equation, what is the "corresponding" autoregressive process?

Comment: Rewrite $(6.1)$ as $\nabla X_n=-(1-\alpha_1)X_{t-1}+N_t$ where $\nabla$ is a backward difference operator on sequences and is a discrete analog of a derivative.

Comment: If $\alpha_1\in [0,1)$, the you have $\alpha=-\log(\alpha_1)$ correspondence. I don't see a correspondence for $\alpha_1\in(-1,0)$ which "flips" the sign of $X_t$ - something Langevin equation cannot do.